# Is there any possibility to make a drop down list of a table in PostGIS using QGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis-custom-widgets

I am trying to create a droplist table filter by id class in PostGIS so that when I start editing in QGIS it will appear as a droplist table with the values or descriptions as I put them in the table.

I can accomplish this task through the QGIS widget attributes form, but this definitely forces me to have the table or tables within table of content, which I do not like it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this task or has experience with how to accomplish it before?
[image].